# Spring filter as Java annotation based bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring filter in the `XML` format provided below,

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I load it as an `XML` file in the top of the class. Will it be possible to write Java instead of the XML definition?

Comment: filters are handled by servlet containers, not by spring container. Not sure the meaning 'Will it be possible to write Java annotation based bean with it?'

Comment: Can I have Java for this instead of the `XML` definition? It will help a lot to know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Spring you should define a class that extends `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` and add following lines to it

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] {
        new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
    };
}
```

You can get more information about filters in Java code from Spring Docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-container-config